# Invalid providers

Tags: angular, angular-providers

I have some difficulties with a provider. I try to import a new custom provider in a component but it doesn't works.
This second provider is based on the first one I made and which works well...

This is my provider :

```
import { Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import ... // All components needed

@Injectable()
export class RoutesHelper {

  private userRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '' , component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
      ...
    ];


  constructor(
    private router:Router
    ) {}

    public load() {
      this.router.resetConfig(this.userRoutes);
    }
}
```

And this is my "QuestionComponent"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RoutesHelper } from '../_utils/routes.helper';

@Component({
  selector: 'questions-list',
  templateUrl: './app/question/questions.component.html',
  providers: [RoutesHelper]
})

export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private routes:RoutesHelper) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routes.load();
  }
}
```

But I have this error :
    Invalid providers for "QuestionsComponent" - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?undefined?]

I don't have any idea why I got "undefined" object neither I have this error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you included your provider in app.module.ts files?

Comment: Yes, the provider is include in app;module.ts

Comment: importing the link as well as including in providers list?

Answer (score 0):

Import the link of the provider in app.module.ts file.

> import { RoutesHelper } from 'give your path';

Include the provider class name in app.module.ts providers list.

> providers: [RoutesHelper, //your other providers...],

In your QuestionComponent just import RoutesHelper link that's it. No need of defining provider.

Comment: I tried and I get a new error : `Can't resolve all parameters for QuestionsComponent: (?)`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved.

to avoid the last error due to import component in provider which is imported in component (so recursive import).
I used this :

```
var userRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '' , component: LeftComponent, outlet: 'left' },
    { path: '' , component: EmptyComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
    { path: '' , component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' }
];

var all = userRoutes.concat(this.router.config);
this.router.resetConfig(all);
```

where userRoutes contains only outlet I want to override and it works.